# String replacements in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text-mining

I need to replace words starting with `www.` with the rest of the link. For example:

```
www.stackoverflow.com
```

with

```
stackoverflow.com
```

I am using pandas. The column that contains the links is called COL1. I have 1000 rows. 
I have tried with

```
df.loc[df['COL1'].str.startswith('www.', na=False), 'NEW_COL']
```

but I do not know what I should replace with in order to take the rest of the link.

Could you please give me advice on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` with regex pattern:

```
df['COL1'] = df['COL1'].str.replace('^(www\.)', '')
```